# Can I guess the appropriate epsilon for RDP (Ramer-Douglas-Peucker)?

Tags: algorithm, simplification

I have sets of time series data which I display as charts in mobile applications.

To make the charts clearer, I simplify the sets by applying [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

If I apply RDP to a small set with an epsilon that's too high, the set becomes over simplified.

Is there any way to asses the appropriate epsilon for a set?

Should I just use the [variation of the algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946754/python-ramer-douglas-peucker-rdp-algorithm-with-number-of-points-instead-of) that specifies the desired number of points?

**EDIT:**
I've managed to work out that if I know more or less how many points I want the set to contain after simplification I can roughly calculate:

```golang
epsilon := (totalNumberOfPoints / (3 * desiredNumberOfPoints)) * 2
```

But I'd love to learn other techniques.